# Resultset to Jtable in Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable, resultset

I want populate jtable1 with resultset using rs2xml.jar in Netbeans. But some errors returns. My code is;

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package program;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils;

/**
 *
 * @author Lacrymae_Ev
 */
public class cagbas extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private static Statement stmt;
    private static Connection con;
    private static final String query = "select 'aicb' as aicb,sum(dur)as dur,sum(tot)as tot from exampletable with(nolock)\n" +
"where date between '2013-07-01 00:00:00.000' and '2013-07-01 23:59:59.999'\n" +
"and id='013'";

    /**
     * Creates new form cagbas
     */
    public cagbas() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 375, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(15, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 275, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(14, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(cagbas.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(cagbas.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(cagbass.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(cagbas.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
 try
 {
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.100.100;" + "databaseName=ExampleDB;" + "user=exampleuser;" +  "password=examplepass;"; 
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        con.close();
 }
 catch(Exception ex)
 {    
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.toString());
 } 
        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new cagbas().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

But **jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));** is not recognized. I generate jtable via Gui Designer in Netbeans and customize creation with **"jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));"**

How can i solve this problem ?

Comment: I don't see where `rs` is defined?  This could, also, produce a `NullPointerException`

Comment: I define it in main method. I run query in main method and reach resultset.

Comment: So, what relationship does `rs` in the `main` method have with the `rs` in `initComponents`?

Comment: Really i dont know :) How can i run this sql statement and parse rs to jtable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a context problem.  `rs` is undefined within the context of `initComponents`, meaning the compiler has no idea what `rs` is.

You would need to define `rs` as an instance variable, like `stmt` and make sure you're not shadowing it in `main`

```
//ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
```

This is a personal thing, but I would highly encourage your to understand what `rs2xml` is actually doing before relying on it

Comment: Thanks for the solution MadProgrammer. rs2xml.jar automaticly setup tablemodel wanted format from rs.

Comment: @Lacrymae *"rs2xml.jar automaticly setup tablemodel wanted format from rs"* But do you actually understand how this is done?  Do you understand how a `TableModel` works. I'll put greater weight on these for a job applicant then I would for someone who knows how to make an API do it.

Comment: Actually i dont investigate deeply. But many users offer this solution for resultsets to jtable automaticly. I am beginner in Java and i just want to learn mechanism step by step.

Comment: @Lacrymae It's up to you, `JTable` is used alot by Swing developers and not always to display data from SQL based results